# How can i get result text in input field ? Its necessary to get text in input field as i am using form.getvalue in my python code

Tags: javascript

This is my code for speech recognition in javascript? I want to get value of result in input field of form. Result is coming in r.innerhtml.
How can i do this ?

i am sharing code below.

```
    <form>
    <input style="font-size: 14px;" id="result">
    </form>
    <button onmousedown="startConverting()" onmouseup="stopConverting()"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var r = document.getElementById('result');
                    var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        function startConverting(){
            if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){

                speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
                speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
                speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
                speechRecognizer.start();

                var finalTranscripts = '';

                speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
                    var interimTranscripts = '';
                    for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
                        var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                        transcript.replace("\\n", "<br>");
                        if(event.results[i].isFinal){
                            finalTranscripts += transcript;
                        }else{
                            interimTranscripts += transcript;
                        }
                    }
                    r.innerText = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color:#999">' + interimTranscripts + '</span>';
                };
                speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {
                };
            }else{
                r.innerText = 'Your browser is not supported. If google chrome, please upgrade!';
            }
        }

        function stopConverting()
        {
                        speechRecognizer.stop();

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is used to take the user's input.
You should not put HTML markup there.

If you wish to get the value of `r`. try `r.value` instead of `r.innerText`

Comment: What is exactly not working? Please see browser console for detail error.